# Html list in handlebar js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, handlebars.js

I want to list the names using handlebarjs. I need the language to be shown as list inside a dropdown.

Now am getting the dropdown with data displayed as a paragraph not list.

Here is the json file..

```
"Data": [
    {
        "FirstName": "Sam",
        "MiddleName": "",
        "LastName": "Thomson",
        "Language": [
            "English",
            "French",
            "Spanish",
            "German",
            "Hindi"

        ]
    }
```

Here is the html file..

```
<td><label rel="popover"  class="btn" data-title="Spl" data-content="{{Language}}"data-placement="bottom" >Language</label>
<div class="" id="spl">
<ul class=" nav"></ul>
</div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need two [block helpers](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html):

1. `with` to "navigate" through the object's properties
2. `each` to iterate over an array

Here is how I would do it:

```
{{with Data}}
  <ul>
  {{each Language}}
    <li>{{this}}</li>
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
{{/with}}
```

You need to do `{{this}}` since your array only contains strings.